# Result on idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with $A^2=A$ and $(A-A^T)^2 =0$. Then $AA^T$ is idempotent.

If $A$ is idempotent then $A^T$ is also idempotent. So, $(A^T)^2 =A^T$. Now, given that $(A-A^T)^2=0$ implies $A^2-A(A^T)-(A^T)A+(A^T)^2=0$, we have that $A-A(A^T)-(A^T)A+A^T=0$.

I cannot proceed further to prove the result. Thank you in advance

Comment: You have been around for three years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Starting from your last equation, first multiply both sides in a smart way with $A$ and $A^T$ to obtain an equality which includes $(A A^T)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0=A(A-AA^T-A^TA+A^T)=A^2-A^2A^T-AA^TA+AA^T$

$=A-AA^T-AA^TA+AA^T=A-AA^TA=0$ implies that $0=(A-AA^TA)A^T=AA^T-AA^TAA^T=AA^T-(AA^T)^2$.